# Is there a particular function to receive the response of a stored procedure with a pivot?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that generates a dynamic table according to the range of days consulted, in the SQL Server application, it works fine, it shows me the result of the "Select" as I hope; but invoking the stored procedure from the site with PHP does not show anything.

In the stored procedure, first I make a table with all the rows that i need, then make the pivot on it.

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Fecha]) 
                from tmp_traficodia_inbound_21
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT * into ##temp from 
         (SELECT 
            [Rut],
            [Agente],
            [Pin Agente],
            [Fecha],
            [Tipificaciones],
            [Total],
            [%]
           from tmp_traficodia_inbound_21) x
        pivot 
        (sum([Tipificaciones])
            for [Fecha] in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute sp_executesql  @query
select * into #temp from ##temp;
drop table ##temp;
select * from #temp;
```

This is the fragment of the PHP code that call the procedure

```
}elseif ($motor_bdd == 'MSSQL') {
    $sql = "exec " . $proceso . " ". $parametros ."";
    $rs = $cnn_campana->prepare($sql);
    $rs->execute();     
}
return $rs;
```

There are a lot of stored procedures called the same way, and this is the first i see that gives problems

After calling the procedure, there is a part that count the columns of the result, and it give me 0

Comment: Could you please show the PHP code you are calling to make the query?  If the stored procedure is returning the expected results the issue may not be with the SQL part of the code.

Comment: There i edit to add the segment of the code that call the procedure from de PHP site